# How to set dialog with full width?

Tags: codenameone

I want to show default dialog and want to increase its width to width of display width , how can it be done?

```
Dialog.show("Message", "this is text", "Ok", null);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that with the default dialogs. You can construct your own `Dialog` object then use methods such as `showStretched` or even `show(int,int,int,int)` but that would require adding the dialog body & OK Button yourself. E.g.:

```
Dialog d = new Dialog("Title", new BorderLayout());
d.add(BoderLayout.CENTER, new SpanLabel("Dialog message body", "DialogBody"));
d.add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, new Button(new Command("OK")));
d.showStretched(BorderLayout.NORTH, true);
```